# Solving line integral without using Green’s theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals, greens-theorem

Good morning everyone, I am a new user here and I have the following problem that I am dealing with since yesterday but I cannot find the correct answer. Here is the problem

Calculate
$$\oint_C (x^2-2xy)dx+(x^2y+3)dy$$
where $C$ is the closed curve of the region bounded by $y^2=8x$ and $x=2$.

Okay, using Green’s theorem, I got
$$\oint_C (x^2-2xy)dx+(x^2y+3)dy=\int_{-4}^4\int_{y^2/8}^{2}(2xy+2x)dxdy=\frac{128}{5}$$
but without using the theorem, I got

The the region bounded by $y^2=8x$ and $x=2$ intersect at $(2,-4)$ and $(2,4)$, hence

The line integral along $x=2$ equals
$$\int_{x=2}^{2}(x^2-2xy)dx+(x^2y+3)dy=0\tag{*}$$
and the line integral along $y^2=8x$ equals
$$\begin{align}\int_{y=4}^{-4}\left(\left(\frac{y^2}{8}\right)^2-2\left(\frac{y^2}{8}\right)y\right)d\left(\frac{y^2}{8}\right)+\left(\left(\frac{y^2}{8}\right)^2y+3\right)dy&=\int_{y=4}^{-4}\left(\frac{5y^5}{256}-\frac{y^4}{16}+3\right)dy\\&=\frac{8}{5}\end{align}$$
So, where is my mistake? Could someone here help me out? Thanks for your comments and answers, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Use parametrisation. That is the trick to do line integral problems. 
Take $y=t$ and $x=\frac{t^2}{8}$ in Path- I and $x=2,dx=0$ in Path-II 
[image] 
So your line integral $$\oint=\oint_{I}+\oint_{II}$$
Now $$\oint_1=\int_{4}^{-4}[(\frac{t^4}{64}-\frac{t^3}{4})\cdot \frac{t}{4}dt+(\frac{t^5}{64}+3)dt]$$
$$=\int_{4}^{-4}[(\frac{t^5}{256}-\frac{t^4}{16}+\frac{t^5}{64}+3)dt]$$
$$=[-\frac{t^5}{64}]_{4}^{-4}$$ since the other functions are odd functions, so their integrals are $0$
$$=\frac{128}{5}$$
And $$\oint_2=\int_{-4}^{4}(4y+3)dy$$
$$=0$$ since the function is odd.

So your answer is $\oint=\frac{128}{5}$

Comment: Can we solve this problem without using Parametrisation because I've never taught that trick yet?

Comment: Yes of course. Like the way you have done. Your line integral for Path-I matches my result. I think you have miscalculated something in the last step. You can compare both of our results. As for the Path-II integral, you have to take $dx=0$ and the limits as I have taken. Or else your answer is quite good. Parametrisation just makes the process easy and never fails. Whereas your process is quite rigorous and laborious (I think you realise that) and might be difficult to work for other problems.

Answer (score 2):

The miscalculation is marked by (*). To calculate the integral on the segment $x=2$ you need to parameterize the segment, for example, as $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))=(2,t)$, $t\colon -4\to 4$, so $dx=0$, $dy=dt$ and the line integral becomes
$$
\int_{-4}^4(4t+3)\,dt=24.
$$
It is only the "projection on $x$"-part of the integral is zero.

P.S. Do not forget to mention (to think of) the *orientation* when dealing with line/surface integrals.

Comment: Will you elaborate your answer in layman's terms because I don't get it yet. Thanks!

Comment: @Fennita Do you know how to systematically calculate line integrals by parametrization? When you first parameterize the integration curve $C\colon (x(t),y(t))$, $t\in[a,b]$ and get a one-dimensional integral wrt $t$ $$\int_C P(x,y)\,dx+Q(x,y)\,dy=\int_a^b(P(x(t),y(t))x'(t)+Q(x(t),y(t))y'(t))\,dt$$.

Comment: Can we solve this problem without using Parametrisation because I've never taught that trick yet?

Comment: @Fennita The trick is the [definition of a line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Definition_2). How did you define a line integral then? Another way to solve a line integral is to use Green's theorem. Yet another to use potential functions (works only for potential vector fields).

Comment: @Fennita Just observe that what you are doing with the second (correctly calculated) integral along $y^2=8x$ is *exactly* the (implicit) parametrization of the curve as $(y^2/8,y)$, $y\colon 4\to -4$, that is $t=y$.